# what is REPL and how/when comes into play?

Tags: redis

Reading a post about [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) I saw this word: **REPL**.

Can someone tell me what It is and how It comes into play during programming maybe adding some simple practical example or scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Read Evaluate Print Loop**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) - basically, the environment you get when using a command-line shell.